# Is it possible to launch external program from Eclipse in multithreaded mode?

Tags: java, eclipse, multithreading

I'm trying to launch a shell with a pipe of commands from Eclipse, something like:

```
/bin/bash -c "external_tool_executable parameters | grep pattern"
```

And grep should be an external program, not a plugin so I can use custom script/program instead.

But when I set the following in "External Tools Configuration:

```
Location:
/bin/bash
Arguments:
-c
"ping -c 10 google.com | grep time"
```

Output appears in the console only when all is finished (without `grep time` all works fine). The process tree shows that external tool is not multithreaded:

```
andrey@andrey-SX58:~$ ps axjf  
PPID   PID  PGID   SID TTY      TPGID STAT   UID   TIME COMMAND  
4164  4165  2145  2145 ?           -1 Sl    1000   2:23          |       \_ /usr/bin/java -Djava.library.path=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/jni/ -Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6  -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -Xms40m -Xmx512m -jar /data/vdt/eclipse_01//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher  
4165  4978  2145  2145 ?           -1 S     1000   0:00          |           \_ /bin/bash -c ping -c 10 google.com | grep time  
4978  4983  2145  2145 ?           -1 S     1000   0:00          |               \_ ping -c 10 google.com  
4978  4985  2145  2145 ?           -1 S     1000   0:00          |               \_ grep time
```

It is different when I'm running from a regular console (w/o Eclipse) - output appears as expected - one line at a time

```
andrey@andrey-SX58:~$ /bin/bash -c 'ping -c 10 google.com | grep time'
andrey@andrey-SX58:~$ ps axjf
PPID   PID  PGID   SID TTY      TPGID STAT   UID   TIME COMMAND
2281  5072  5072  5072 pts/27    5121 Ss    1000   0:00          |   \_ /bin/bash
5072  5121  5121  5072 pts/27    5121 S+    1000   0:00          |       \_ /bin/bash -c ping -c 10 google.com | grep time
5121  5122  5121  5072 pts/27    5121 S+    1000   0:00          |           \_ ping -c 10 google.com
5121  5123  5121  5072 pts/27    5121 S+    1000   0:00          |           \_ grep time
```

Am I missing some stupid option?

Andrey

Update1: I was wrong, process tree only showed "l" for the Eclipse application, not for the bash in a standalone mode.
I was suggested to use `--line-buffered` with grep, and it works - but I still do not understand why it works, and why it is not needed when shell is launched from console.

Comment: Just from a pure curisoity standpoint,  how are you able tell this is not multithreaded by the process tree?

Answer (score 0):

According to [grep(1)](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/grep.1.html):

> ```
>  --line-buffered
>          Force output to be line buffered.  By default, output is line buffered when standard output is
>          a terminal and block buffered otherwise.
> ```

Eclipse *probably* do not use a proper stream to catch the output of launched processes. **ping** probably doesn't care and just output and flush on any tty, while grep have a different approach as defined in the man page.

**grep** detects (using [isatty(3)](http://linux.die.net/man/3/isatty)) that it is not running over a stream object and thus do not flush every line.

A simple program can show this behaviour on bash (mygrep):

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
 printf("isatty: %s\n", isatty(fileno(stdout))? "true": "false");
 return 0;
}
```

If you run this using a pipe, like this:

> $ ping google.com | ./mygrep

you'll see:

> isatty: true

But using:

> $ ./mygrep > tempfile

you'll get:

> isatty: false

Comment: And regarding the multithread issue, I believe Eclipse don't have a chance to prevent multithread mode from launched tools. What you saw was just the effect buffering on grep.